# Standard lookup values dialog box disappears on type ahead

Tags: custom-object, lookup-field, type-ahead

I'm facing a weird issue. I have a standard record page on a custom object - `Approval_Norms__c` and have a lookup field related to another custom object - `Approval_Master__c`.

Lets say if I have a `Approval_Master__c` record with name field as "Sample" and when I type "Sa" on its related lookup field placed on `Approval_Norms__c` page layout, then 5 recent records are visible. When I continue to type "Sam", then the dialog box dropdown of the lookup values disappears and no results are rendered. Nevertheless, I can choose any one of the lookup value with just "Sa" typed, but after I type the 3rd character no lookup values are rendering.

OWD is public read write for both objects and record is visible. No sharing issues or access issue on the field, no lookup filter too.

Randomly when I tried to edit one of the `Approval_Master__c`, like a dummy update without changing any value, it works. All the lookups dialog box values are rendered when the entire text "Sample" is typed.

I want to know why this happens ? And is there a way to make this work without the need to perform a dummy update ? Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks